# ModalUIview, not dismiss but transition / fade into ViewController

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIView` that I display modally, This view hosts an `imageview`, I am trying to create a vehavior that when the user clicks on a button ( like select ) instead of dimissing the modal window I do a fade in ( transition ) from the modal window back to the `Viewcontroller`, and make that image the background of the parent `viewcontroller`, I couldn't find anything quite like this behavior online.

Any ideas?

Comment: just set alpha value of the view to from 0 to 1 according to your need

Comment: cant you just use `UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve`

Answer (score 0):

Set up custom hide and show methods for your view. Something like this:

```
- (void)show:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (animated) {

        __weak StoryMetadataView * blockSelf = self;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:kShowHideDuration animations:^{
            blockSelf.alpha = 1.0;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];
    } else {
        self.alpha = 1.0;
    }
}

- (void)hide:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (animated) {

        __weak StoryMetadataView * blockSelf = self;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:kShowHideDuration animations:^{
            blockSelf.alpha = 0.0;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [blockSelf removeFromSuperview];
        }];
    } else {
        self.alpha = 0.0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something along these lines.

1. Create an image from your modal controller's view.
2. Insert, in the window's hierarchy, ViewController's view underneath the modal controller's view
3. Set the background color of ViewController's view using the image you created (colorWithPatternImage:)
4. Fade out the modal controller's view
5. dismiss the modal view controller without animation